# How to install PEAR with EasyPHP 5.3.8?

Tags: php, windows-7, phpunit, pear, easyphp

I'm learning Yii and following [ebook written by Jeffrey Winesett](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847199585), the application is built upon TDD. So I need to install PHPUnit to write unit test, which leads me to posts help installing PEAR for my Windows 7 (ref. [link 1](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php), [link 2](http://mikereynolds.wordpress.com/2008/04/23/easyphp-pear-on-windows-get-php-mysql-phpmyadmin-and-my-tweak-for-getting-pear-to-work/)).

And in those above sites, the author keep telling to use `go-pear.bat` **which doesn't exist** in my EasyPHP 5.3.8 which also be the latest version at the time of speaking.

Even in [this EasyPHP forum post](http://www.easyphp.org/forums/47/149305) we cannot find the answer.

So the question is, how to install PEAR with EasyPHP 5.3.8?

I'm using:

- Netbeans PHP 7.0.1 as IDE for PHP.
- EasyPHP 5.3.8 as A M P package

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the script go-pear.php doesn't work on some new php version. 
My solution :

dowload in php folder the file from http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar

(use the windows console in mode admin) and from php folder type :
php go-pear.phar

Comment: your go-pear.phar does not work... manifest cannot be larger than 100 MB

Answer (score 9):

In earlier versions of EasyPHP there is a BAT file that does the PEAR installation steps for you...

`C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.6.0\php\go-pear.bat`

It also has most of the file-paths preconfigured, so you don't really need to change anything.

---

**UPDATE:**
So EasyPHP 5.3.8 and 5.3.9 don't seem to have this BAT file, so these are the steps I needed to take to get the PEAR library installed.

- Rename 
  `\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.9\php\php539x120203095725\php.ini` 
  to `php.ini.disabled`
  This is because I found the local ini file caused lots of extension errors.  I don't think this file is used by Apache, so you can probably leave it disabled.
- Add two folders to your Windows `PATH`.
  (Press `Win+Pause` to open System Settings > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables > System Variables > Double-click Path.)
  Keep the existing folders there, but add another two, separated by semi-colons `;`

  - Your `php.exe` folder.  On my machine this was: `c:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.9\php\php539x120203095725`
  - The location you would like to install PEAR.  I used `D:\Dev\PEAR`
- Download http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
- Shift + Right-Click the folder you downloaded `go-pear.phar` to > Open command window here
- Type `php go-pear.phar`
- Press enter to install system-wide PEAR (the default)
- Type 1 to change the installation base.  I chose `D:\Dev\PEAR`.  The other settings should be OK to leave as default.  Press enter again (twice) when prompted.
- Run the REG file that was just created.  You can type `D:\Dev\PEAR\PEAR_ENV.reg` and click yes when prompted.
- Check that you have the latest version by typing:

  ```
  pear channel-update pear.php.net
  pear upgrade
  ```
- Ensure your web-apps can use the PEAR library, by editing `EasyPHP-5.3.9\conf_files\php.ini`
  and uncommenting the `include_path` directive and adding your PEAR path to the end.  *Note that you have to use PEAR/pear.* Example:

  ```
  include_path = ".;${path}\php\includes;d:\Dev\PEAR\pear"
  ```

  EasyPHP will automatically restart Apache for you.

You can then proceed to install other modules.  For example, phpUnit is installed by typing:

```
pear config-set auto_discover 1
pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit
```

Comment: Your EasyPHP is 5.3.6.0, old version. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Oops, I should have properly read your original post, sorry.  Yeah, 5.3.6 has the BAT file, but it's missing also on my work computer using EasyPHP 5.3.9.  :-(

Comment: give the go-pear.bat

Answer (score 3):

I'm just going to assume that ""EasyPHP"" has a normal/real php-cli interface.

- Download http://pear.php.net/go-pear and save it to the filesystem as go-pear.php
- Move to the directory where your saved your file
- Run: `php go-pear.php` and answer all the questions it asks you

That usually (as in X/M/WTF-AMP stacks) works much more reliable than trying to get an outdated version of pear running from something that is just mean to glue php and apache together.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is the translation in french, with some more comments :**
**Voici la traduction en français, avec quelques commentaires supplémentaires.**

1. Créez un dossier PEAR_install dans le dossier d'EasyPHP. Ce dossier servira à déposer le fichier phar d'installation, et vous pouvez éventuellement y signaler que vous installez PEAR dans C:\php\PEAR par exemple.

   ```
   C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\PEAR_install
   ```
2. Téléchargez dans le dossier PEAR_install le fichier issu de http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
3. Ajoutez deux dossiers dans le PATH :

   Rappel : Pour accéder aux variables d’environnement sous Windows : Pressez Win+Pause pour ouvrir les Paramètres Système > Paramètres avancés > Variables d'environnement > Variables système > Double-cliquez sur "Path".

   Gardez bien les dossiers existants dans la variable path, et ajoutez juste les deux nouveaux dossiers séparés par des points-virgule.

   Tout d’abord le dossier qui contient php.exe :

   ```
   C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\php;
   ```

   Ensuite le dossier où vous souhaitez installer PEAR :

   ```
   C:\php\pear;
   ```

   On aurait aussi bien sûr pu choisir :

   ```
   C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\pear;
   ```

   Mais ce choix n'est peut-être pas le meilleur au cas où vous voudriez passer à une version plus récente d'EasyPHP.
   Ne pas oublier de mettre le point virgule à la fin de chaque ajout
4. Dans une fenêtre de commande, lancer la commande

   ```
   C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\PEAR\php go-pear.phar
   ```

   Bien entendu, il faut bien lire les warnings qui s’affichent et agir en conséquence
5. Lancer le fichier REG qui a été créé dans C:\php\pear\PEAR_ENV.reg
6. Si ce n'est pas déjà fait, ajoutez dans le path le dossier C:\php\pear
7. Vérifiez que vous avez la dernière version de PEAR en tapant :

   ```
    C:\php\pear\pear channel-update pear.php.net
    C:\php\pear\pear upgrade
   ```
8. Vérifiez que vos web-apps peuvent utiliser la librairie PEAR en éditant le fichier de configuration (EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\conf_files\php.ini) puis en décommentant la directive include_path et en ajoutant à la fin de cette directive votre dossier PEAR.Voir l’exemple ci-dessous, et notez bien que vous devez utiliser PEAR/pear

   ```
   include_path = ".;${path}\php\includes;d:\Dev\PEAR\pear"
   ```

   Dans notre cas ce sera :

   ```
   include_path = ".;${path}\php\includes;c:php\pear\pear"
   ```
9. EasyPHP va redémarrer Apache pour vous de façon automatique.
   Vous pouvez ensuite vous lancer dans l’installation d’autres modules.

   Par exemple, vous pouvez installer le module PHPUnit en tapant :

   ```
   pear config-set auto_discover 1
   pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit
   ```