# Cannot install PEAR with EasyPHP 13.1 VC9

Tags: pear, easyphp

I'm trying to install PEAR on my newly installed EasyPHP 13.1. Basically, I'm following the steps described here: [How to install PEAR with EasyPHP 5.3.8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471603/how-to-install-pear-with-easyphp-5-3-8)

The problem is that when I run command "php go-pear.phar" (as administrator), I get the following error message: Could not open input file: go-pear.phar

I even tried to download and run the non-phared file from http://pear.php.net/go-pear, but I got the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turned out that before running command "php go-pear.phar", the current working directory must be set to the directory which contains go-pear.phar (with command cd).

Answer (score 2):

Does the `go-pear.phar` file exist in the directory your are currently in and are executing php right now?

Learn about the "current working directory" of a shell.

Comment: I did not realize that my working directory has to be the same as the directory which contains go-pear.phar. Now it works. Thanks.